# Add new mongoDB document with object type

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm totally new to mongoDB, just coming from MySQL, so I'm trying to add a new document to a mongo database in Node.js, I have the code working except when I have to include a custom object.

Here's my code:

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const book= new Book({
        title: req.body.book.title,
        year_published: req.body.book.year_published,
        author: req.body.author    // ==> here is the problem without it works fine (comes the full author via body parameter)
    });

    try {
        const savedBook = await book.save();
        
        res.json({
           insertedBook: savedBook
        });
    } catch (err) {
        //console.log("Error:" + err);
        
        res.json({error: err});
    }
});
```

The book and author models (simplified):

```
 // ======= AUTHORS ================ //

    var mongoose         = require('mongoose');
    var mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate-v2');     
    
    const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: {
             type: String,
             required:true
             },
        place_birth: {
                    type: String,
                    required:true}, 
    
    });
    
    schema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);
    
    const Authors = mongoose.model('Authors',schema);
    
    module.exports = Authors;

 // ======= BOOKS ================ //
    var mongoose         = require('mongoose');
    var mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate-v2');     
    
    var ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;
    
    const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
        title: {
             type: String,
             required:true
             },
        year_published: {
                    type: String,
                    required:true}, 
        author: [{
            type: ObjectId,
            ref: 'Authors', 
            required:false
        }],
    });
    
    schema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);
    
    const Books = mongoose.model('Books',schema);
    
    module.exports = Books;
```

Data posting:

```
{
    "book": {
        "title": "Entrada con cuernos",
        "year_published": "2020",
    },
    "author": {
                "name": "Marcus", 
                "place_birth": "Moscow",
    }
}
```

What's the proper way to insert a book document?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When creating a new `Book`, `Book.author` should be a [mongoose document](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html), meaning the Author should exist in the mongoDB already.

You need to first save the Author in the DB, then pass it in `Boot.author` with it's `Author._id` property set

P.S.: Use singular words when describing your collections:

```js
const Authors = mongoose.model('Authors',schema);
const Authors = mongoose.model('Author',schema); // recommended
```

[mongoose will take care of the plural naming](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html#compiling)

> The first argument is the singular name of the collection your model is for. Mongoose automatically looks for the plural, lowercased version of your model name

Comment: yes, is a json object. Yes, can be 1 or multiple authors.

Comment: What exactly is inside `req.body.author` is it a mongoose document with a propoer _id?

Comment: The author must be a valid mongoose document, meaning it should be an Author that you already persisted in the MongoDB, and already has an _id. Check updated answer

Comment: Thanks! I'll implement that!

Comment: If the question was answered, could you please mark my answer as correct? thanks, good luck. @MarcoMartin